# How to display searchresults in alphabetical order in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi in my application I have a to search few elements and the result have to show in tableview. For example if the elements are

NS1,NSE2,NAse3,NWe3,Nxw,NB22 like this if I search for N then the data have to display as such below

```
NAse3
NB22
NSE2
NS1
NWe3
Nxw.
```

Please let me know how to implement this.

Now I am using the below code I am performing the search.

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    if([array count]!=0){
        array2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0 ];
        for(NSMutableDictionary *data in array){
            r = [[data objectForKey:@"Product"] rangeOfString:searchBar.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if(r.location != NSNotFound){
                 if(r.location== 0)
                     [array2 addObject:data];
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code? how you implemented your search functionality?

Comment: Hi Pratyusha thanks for your response. I am editing my question please check.

Comment: ok naresh garu 5 minutes lo answer post chesthanu :)

Comment: check if it is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    if([array count]!=0)
    {
        array2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];

        for(NSMutableDictionary *data in array)
        {
            r = [[data objectForKey:@"Product"] rangeOfString:searchBar.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

            if(r.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                 if(r.location== 0)
                 [array2 addObject:data];
             }
       }
       NSSortDescriptor *sortDis = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Product"
                      ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
      [array2 sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDis]];
    }
}
```

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40716/discussion-between-naresh-and-pratyusha-terli)

Answer (score 1):

try this to sort your results:

```
array2 = [array2 sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
    return [a compare:b options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

Comment: blocks look promising

Answer (score 0):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"your Key"
                                              ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [drinkDetails sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Using custom comparator-methods is possible Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html).